# Change Rundeck log file to a file owned by root changes rundeckd daemon to root

Tags: rundeck

I have changed the rundeckd log configuration file to another file which is owned by root. I have implemented this by changing the file which is located in "/rundeck/server/config/rundeck-config.properties". I have added the entry : "server.logDir=[NewPath]". Before this change, the rundeckd daemon was executed with the user which have installed rundeckd [this user is in the sudoers file ]. After this change, the rundeckd daemon is executed with root. I want to know if it is possible to change the log file to a file owned by root without changing the user which executes the rundeckd daemon.

I tried to change the log file and after applying the new change the rundeckd daemon is executed by root instead of the user which installed rundeckd.I was hoping that the user who launches the rundeckd process had not been changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `rundeck` user can write only `rundeck` user logs, if you change any `rundeck` user component only for the `root` user, the `rundeck` user can't "reach it", of course, you can run Rundeck as root but that's dangerous, an essential Rundeck-on-linux advice is: don't run Rundeck as `root` user (e.g: you can break your server dispatching local commands as `root` user).